# javascript cookies, create and delete

Tags: javascript, cookies, page-refresh

I'm working on a page that refreshes itself every 5 minutes

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1200;url=?meta_refresh=true" />
```

On the page is a JS script that should run the first two times the page reloads. When the page reload's for the third time, the script should not execute.

So far, I've created a cookie and given it an initial value of 0, for every refresh I increment it's value (rewrite the cookie) and if the value is smaller than 3 i execute the part of a script. The things is that if I close the tab and reopen the page in another tab, the cookie has the incremented value, and I want it to always start from 0.

Here's what i've done so far:

```js
var value = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {

  function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
      var c = ca[i];
      while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
      if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
  }

  function checkCookie() {
    var cookieValue = getCookie('siteRefreshCookie');
    if (cookieValue !== '') {
      var newValue = parseInt(getCookie('siteRefreshCookie')) + 1;
      if (newValue < 3) {
        //script to be executed
        document.cookie = "siteRefreshCookie="+ newValue +";";
      }
    } else {             
      document.cookie = "siteRefreshCookie="+ value +";";
    }
  }
  checkCookie();
})
```

Comment: Maybe just reset the cookie when the tab is closed. You can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclose, the `onclose` event.

Answer (score 1):

Could I suggest using a query string instead?

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1200;url=?meta_refresh=true&count=1" />
```

Then as an ASP programmer myself I would do something like:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1200;url=?meta_refresh=true&count=<%=CInt(0 & Request.Querystring("count")) + 1%>" />
```

But you can probably achieve this using PHP, or even JS I imagine if you have no back-end language suitable.

The problem with using cookies is that they are tied to that website, rather than that window. Even if you reset the cookie with an unload function like Pete suggested, you'll then run into problems like if for example you have two tabs open with the same page.